# Multiple Regex on one string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to search a string for Youtube url's and mp3 url's...and replace each with a player.

Here's the code:

```
    $patterns = array();
    $patterns[0] = '#(http://)(www.)(?:youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com/(?:[^/]+/.+/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)/|.*[?&]v=)|youtu\.be/)([^"&?/ ]{11})#x';
    $patterns[1] = '((https?:\/\/)?(\w+?\.)+?(\w+?\/)+\w+?.(mp3|ogg))';

    $replacements = array();
    $replacements[0] = '<iframe width="640" height="385" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/\\3" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
    $replacements[1] = '<a id="m5" class="audio {skin:"green", autoPlay:false, addShadow:false,addGradientOverlay:true}" href="\\0">Beaver Radio Network</a>';
    $brnpost = 'This is our story content.  Here is the youtube link: <br /><br /> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qvwefWgIQhY <br /><br />Listen Here: http://beaverradionetwork.com/audio/1011/brnpodcasts/leonhardt_skaar_2015.mp3';

echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $brnpost);
```

`

If I run each Regex individually, it works. If I join them into the array, it takes part of the mp3 link and puts it in the Youtube embed. Like this:

```
This is our story content.  Here is the youtube link
<br /><br /> 
    <iframe width="640" height="385" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/leonhardt_s" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>kaar_2015.mp3
</body>
```

The Youtube embed is showing PART of the mp3 replacement...and the rest of the mp3 replacement is showing up in the mp3 link.  When placed together, the two patterns make them both fail.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Why is it taking one replacement...and splitting the result into BOTH pattern matches?

Comment: Did you try putting each pattern between slashes? `/pattern/`

Comment: Yes I did...I figured it out late last night what was wrong.  The Youtube regex was wrong.  It didn't stop at whitespace after the video ID.  Correct...and working...pattern is now: `#(http://)(www.)(?:youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com/(?:[^/\s]+/.+/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)/|[^?&\s]*[?&]v=)|youtu\.be/)([^"&?/ ]{11})#x`